# Different Selenium Bindings

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we be encouraging selenium questions to include the bindings they are using. There have been a few questions about how to do stuff with selenium, however, it's sometimes hard to give an answer without knowing the bindings they are using.

Should we be tagging selenium and .net, java, ruby, etc... so that more targeted answers can be given?

Answer (score 1):

You should tag Selenium questions with the relevant binding.  Yes, tags are ambiguous -- does a Java tag connote a question about testing Java programs or Selenium's Java binding? -- but the same is true of tags in many systems.  Nonetheless, a tagged question is better than an untagged question.

I do not recommend using a "testing" tag.

Answer (score 1):

If people aren't going to actively tag their post with a language binding, they should at least specify in the OP what language they're using. The vast majority of Selenium questions posted don't specify.

On StackOverflow everyone uses tags to indicate the language. Not sure why it would have a different meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

I find benefit in tagging appropriately to reach the right experts for the question. I don't think this is a debate in anyone's mind.

Let's say, however, that someone follows the [java](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. What kinds of questions would they expect to see?

- Questions about testing Java programs
- Questions about testing using a Java framework (JUnit) (This will usually fall under the first one as well, but doesn't necessarily need to.)
- Questions about testing using a Java binding for a generic framework (Selenium's Java binding)

For me, I would follow it for testing Java programs. But, I think it would be more popular to see it for one of the other two. I would think any of those reasons (and probably others too) would be fine for tagging a question with Java. It would also seem like that someone following the [java](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) tag for a question about Selenium's Java binding would also be likely to be willing and able to answer ones on JUnit.